# How to enable tab complete only in term-line-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have company-mode installed. When I press tab in term-mode, it always calls company-complete. 
I tried to disable company-mode with

```
(global-company-mode '(not (equal major-mode 'term-mode)))
```

Also the following is not working

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda()
(company-mode 0)
(global-unset-key (kbd "<tab>"))))
```

I tried another approach with this

```
(defun term-send-tab()
(interactive)
(term-send-raw-string "\t"))

(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "TAB") 'term-send-tab)
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "<tab>") 'term-send-tab)
```

All failed. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your first line doesn't make sense. Try `(setq company-global-modes '(not term-mode))`.

Comment: This disables company mode for term-mode. How to enable company mode in term-line-mode only?

Comment: That's not trivial: `term-line-mode` is not a real major or minor mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with my customised function my-tab with some code written by phil.I bind tab key to my-tab, it will send a raw tab when in term-char-mode and do complete in other cases, also two quick tab will do yas-expand, by binding yas-next-field to "M-n", tab completion even works inside a snippet expansion.

The problem is when company and yasnnipet has the same prefix, then tab only do completion. Is it possible to set a delay time for company completion after tab key press, make it greater than my-double-key-timeout, so double tab will do yas-expand, if the user want company completion, he can just type one tab and wait. (sovled with sit for)

I don't know why I can't just bind tab to send a raw tab in term-raw-map.

```
(defvar my-double-key-timeout 0.25
  "The number of seconds to wait for a second key press.")

 (defun my-tab ()
  "Move to the beginning of the current line on the first key stroke,
and to the beginning of the buffer if there is a second key stroke
within `my-double-key-timeout' seconds."
  (interactive)
  (let ((last-called (get this-command 'my-last-call-time)) )
        (is-term (string= "term-mode" major-mode)))
    (if (and is-term (term-in-char-mode))
    (term-send-raw-string "\t")
      (if (and (eq last-command this-command)
           last-called
           (<= (time-to-seconds (time-since last-called))
           my-double-key-timeout))
      (yas-expand) 

            (if (sit-for my-double-key-timeout)
             (complete-indent-fold)))

    (put this-command 'my-last-call-time (current-time))))

(defun complete-indent-fold()
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-at outline-regexp)
      (if (equal major-mode 'org-mode) (org-cycle) (my-outline-cycle))
    (if (looking-at "\\_>") (company-complete) (indent-for-tab-command))))
```

Please help me make this better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It still have a little bug, but work good for me. Any suggests are welcome!

```
(defun my-tab ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((str (thing-at-point 'line t))
    (ep nil))
    (setq str (replace-regexp-in-string "^.*\\$ " "" str))
    (setq ep (- (length str) 1))
    (goto-char (line-beginning-position))
    (delete-region (point) (line-end-position))
    (term-send-raw-string
     (format "\r%s\t\t" (substring str 0 ep)))))

(define-key term-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'my-tab)
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.